# Processing Key Strokes in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a program that converts a keyboard character from it's ASCII value into binary. When I create the events in the windows form, it doesn't show up what key has been entered, and the Key menu in properties only shows PreviewKeyDown option.

I just want the program to first show up what key was entered into the form itself.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ica5_eventdriven
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            lblKey.Text = " "+ e.KeyChar;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            labelkey.Text = " " + e.KeyCode;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            labelkey.Text = " ";
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: With my code, I have created three events for keystroke. When I go to the menu and try to add those events in the Key event section, the KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress don't show up. Without those, the key stroke won't be processed. How am I going to add that in the design itself and the code?

Answer (score 0):

All Events have two arguments: object sender and EventArgs e. If there is any inforamtion like wich key was presed around, it will be in the EventArgs for the event. That is the EventArgs purpose.

Like [KeyPressEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx).

Note that where you register the event maters a lot. You could get anywhere from "not noticing the Keypress because someone else handeled it" to "reporting the same keypress multiple times".